# UIToolbar with images and titles like UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

is it possible to create a `UIToolBar` containing `UIBarItems` with both, images and titles for better explaining the function behind the item? A `UITabBar` is designed to select 1 of n items. The current item is highlighted. This is not what I need. I'm needing to call a function without selecting the current toolbat item!

Answer (score 1):

No.  The toolbar is not designed to have both an image and a text tag.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I undertand the question, but if you want to add an image to the UINavigationBar Button then you cannot do that. You can however, add a background image to this button and pad your text with spaces: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1649012&tstart=0

Edit: also see this: [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar)

Answer (score 0):

i may be understanding your question wrong, but isn't that the default behaviour of UITabBar?

EDIT: w. comments

It wouldn't be too hard to subclass UIViewController with a UIView containing UIButtons & UILabels to suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, but UITabBar is designed to select 1 from n.
The current item is highlighted. This is not what I need.
I'm needing to call a function without selecting the current toolbat item

Comment: ah, i c.  you should update your question to include this extra info.