# UINavigiationBar left / back image scaled?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Trying to use a nice 'back' arrow image, like that found in Apple's iPod app - when I add my 30x30 image it seems to squashed or scaled, as it looks tiny?

Is it possible that the UINavigationBar's back item will have to be custom view perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quote from Apple's View Controller Programming Guide which you might find helpful:

> To assign a custom button or view to the left position, and thereby replace the default Back button, assign a UIBarButtonItem object to the leftBarButtonItem property.

The UIBarButtonItem class has a call to initWithImage which allows you to set the view with an image of your choosing.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This was what I was after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar