# iPhone : making UIBarButtonItem that is arrow shaped

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem on a navigation bar. I'd like to make it arrow shaped. By that I mean I want it to be square except for a pointy side. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrestled with several approaches on this one and finally figured it out using all the answers from several sources.  There are a couple of tricks; this snippet will show it all (I was creating a custom `rightNavButton`, but you can adapt this easily for any `UIBarButtonItem`):

```
// Produces a nice "right arrow" style button that mirrors the back arrow
// automatically added by the navController
//
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"forwardButton.png"];
UIButton *forwardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[forwardButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[forwardButton setTitle:@"Meter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
forwardButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
forwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[forwardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMeter) 
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
           initWithCustomView:forwardButton];
```

Note: it turns out that if you try to set the target and action directly on the button item after assigning a custom view using a `UIButton` that it won't take - you have to set the target and action on the button itself - apparently the `navBar` uses the button provided verbatim.

<strike>This is the image I was using on the opaque black `navBar` (you can use anything, obviously): http://raretiger.com/images/forwardbutton.png</strike>

Comment: You can download, Retina compatible, transparent images here: [link]http://handleopenurl.com/assets/docs/arrow-buttons.zip[/link]
The back arrow has a leftCap of 15, the forward of 5. (at normal size buttons.)

Comment: You've got a memory leak where you're allocating `UIBarButtonItem` 'retain +1' and then assigning it to the property `rightBarButtonItem` 'retain +1'. Which means that UIBarButtonItem will now have a retain count of 2 and will never get released. You need to autorelease UIBarButtonItem:

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
           initWithCustomView:forwardButton] autorelease];`

Answer (score 7):

Make a custom background. See [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar) for how.

---

You may `-pushNavigationItem:animated:` to make the built-in back button appear, although you cannot assign custom actions to it.

---

For undocumented methods, you may use

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
```

to create a back "button".

Comment: @Matt: That's not a built-in button type.

Comment: Quick hack, a bit too late: a forward button is a back button with a transform=scale(-1,1) and whose textLabel has a transform=scale(-1,1).

Comment: If you were to use [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; how would you go about changing the "tintColor"?

Comment: @kennytm how make it in Swift?

Answer (score 4):

You could create an UIImageView or an UIButton with the required image then use:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: arrowButton];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

continuing on @Plamen Dragozov's idea: i noticed if you leave the uibutton as is, it would trigger a picture adjustment when touched and that is quite the opposite what a normal navigation back button does. So what I did was to uncheck "highlighted adjusts Image" and it  works like a charm.

hope this helps newbies like me.

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution:

```
UIBarButtonItem * backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];
[backButtonItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]      forState:UIControlStateNormal     barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was renaming the back button that appears on the pushed view controller. I found a dirty workaround and if you ignore the non-ideal animation problem, you'll get a back button with the title you want.

The trick is to change the title of the first VC in `viewWillDisappear` and re-set it of course in `viewWillAppear`

(Needless to say, by default, if there is no `leftBarButtonItem` set, `UINavigationController` will show a back button with the title of the VC that pushed the current VC)

In the VC where you push your current VC, do

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  self.title = @"Back";
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.title = @"Original Title";
}
```