# How can I modify the target of the default Back button on iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to have the default shape of the back button, but that makes my program enter a loop at some point.
The code is this for modifying the text of the back button, written before the initialization of the view.

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];

[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

[newBackButton release];
```

can I also change the target to another view? I really need that default shape and I don't know how else to get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UINavigationController does not work that way, you'll need to make a custom [UIBarButton with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330157/iphone-making-uibarbuttonitem-that-is-arrow-shaped).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the right-button in the navigation controller you usually set the `backBarButtonItem` on the **parent** view controller, i.e. the one you are going back to.

```
    parentViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to modify the target of the back button on [this blog](http://www.hanspinckaers.com/custom-action-on-back-button-uinavigationcontroller). The key idea is to subclass `UINavigationController` and override the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method. First paste in your custom code and then call `[super popViewControllerAnimated:animated]` at the end.

I have verified that this still works fine in SDK 4.3.