# How can I add default left arrow in leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I used third party code (menu) in my application to change my navigation controller back button title. Therefore I used code like this:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Geri" style :UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(myCustomBack)] autorelease];
```

This code work fine but there is no default left arrow image in iOS 7, also rectangle button created in iOS 6. How can I add default left image (not custom) in back button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating back arrow shaped leftBarButtonItem on UINavigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310454/creating-back-arrow-shaped-leftbarbuttonitem-on-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: If I set custom left arrow button, there is different left button in ios 6, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need own arrow image.

Create regular `UIButton` with custom style and background image (arrow) also set action, then create `UIBarButtonItem` and put this button as custom view;