# back button in a modal viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone : making UIBarButtonItem that is arrow shaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330157/iphone-making-uibarbuttonitem-that-is-arrow-shaped)  
>   [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba)

I have a modal viewController with a navigation bar.
And, I want to create a back button on a modal viewcontroller.
Now, I am aware of the following method :-

```
[self.delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and for now, I'm calling it from a leftBarButtonItem.

But, my problem is exactly that. It's a leftBarButtonItem that looks like a regular leftBarButtonItem.
While, what I want is a button that looks like a backBarButtonItem with the pointy/arrow-like left side.

EDIT: **I have reasons for specifically wanting to use a modal viewController and a back button. Kindly refrain from telling me to not use either one of the two. Thanks.**

Comment: You are duplicating this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330157/iphone-making-uibarbuttonitem-that-is-arrow-shaped?lq=1  and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to fake it with a custom image but in reality that's breaking the default behavior since the arrow implies navigation but a modal view controller is usually within the context of the current view controller and not moving forward or backwards. Your current solution may be the best.

Comment: You should really be using a blue "done" button, not a navigation button.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have reasons for wanting to use the back button, instead of the "done" button or leftBarButtonItem.

@rooster117 Any pointers for what I should be looking at, to fake it with a custom image?

Comment: as suggested by @rooster117, push your view controller onto the navigation stack, don't use it as a modal vc.  Then you'll get back navigation as expected

Comment: @CSmith I have reasons for wanting to use a modal viewController just like I have reasons for wanting to use the back button.

Comment: Modal views are dismissed (i.e. closed), not navigated back from.  You're getting the right feedback here, read the Apple HIG document for more information.

Comment: @CSmith Yes, I am aware of that, thanks for nothing!

Comment: First you're going to have to get the back button image and just look at how to add a custom button with image to the bar. I would recommend using this project to get native artwork for this use or any other time you want native looking art: https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/