# How to make a UIBarButtonItem look like a UINavigationBarItem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I have an iPad application with screen flows which don't map neatly to the navigation controller model, but still have the concept of "Back".

I'd like to manage my own toolbar and have a "Back" button where I decide where it goes.

Is there a way to make a toolbar button have the look of a back button as in UINavigationBarItem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you either have to use undocumented APIs, or create a custom button with a custom image.

This question:

[Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar)

has answers that cover both ways.

(Placing a UINavigationBar back button look alike icon somewhere other than the left of what looks like a UINavigationBar is probably against the HIG and may result in non-approval of the application, though perhaps only if you're unlucky.)

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I wanted to hear.