# UIBarButton as a backbutton style

Tags: iphone

Hi 
 i'm displaying UIBarButton on Navigation bar as back button,how can i've the default back button style for the UIButton.

Regards
Sam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the parent view controller when pushing the view in didselectrowInIndex method just use the following cod:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem release];
```

Answer (score 1):

three20 includes a custom style for back-like buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom button with navigation button image.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar)

What you are looking for can be done by making a custom UIButton

Comment: i tried "AndrewS" answer but did not work out.is there any way that i can achieve this by code rather than an image

Comment: No. Make a custom UIButton. Its not that hard.