# Create a table view for adding Title and Note in iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am creating an application on iPhone for displaying world maps.I have created Tab bar controller as the rootViewController. On one of the tabs, I need to provide an option for saving current status of map as an image.

For this purpose, 
1) I need to provide a 'SAVE' and 'CLEAR' button in the Navigation bar.
and
2) 'Title' and 'Note' fields are to be provided as table view to make it look nice.
   User will tap into the table cell and write the corresponding data into the fields.

Please suggest me some direction or give some sample code if available..
(I will explain the above problem in detail if someone is not able to understand it properly)
Please reply..
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

**First-** You can get an idea with this link:
[Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar)

**Second-** You have to find in WWDC 2010's:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/
You have to see title name is 'Mastering Table View'.But you will need apple id to log in.