# Isn't a 2-byte char datatype insufficient to deal with the concept of "characters" in a Unicode string?

Tags: string, unicode, char, unicode-string, codepoint

Various programming languages use a 2-byte `char` datatype (not to be confused with C/C++'s `char`, which is just one byte) out of which strings are constructed. Various utility functions will try to find such a `char` in a string, like looking for an `e` in `hello`, or do other operations that accept or return `char`s (split, indexof, replace, count number of character occurrences in a string, length, ...).

If you dig deeper you will find out about Unicode code points. And indeed, Java (and I assume other languages as well) lets you iterate those code points. But those seem to be represented by an `int` (4 bytes) not a `char` (2 bytes). Very rarely, if ever will you see people using code points to iterate through a string. Since such a code point may span multiple `char`s (max 2, right? `int`?) it's not the fastest way to do string operations, but it does seem to be the correct way.

Some programs/frameworks/operating systems(?) will also fail to work correctly with multi-`char` characters, instead only deleting the second `char` of it and creating a "corrupted" character.

Shouldn't you always use the methods that operate on code points when dealing with strings? What am I missing? I'm afraid someone will have to explain to me why the world keeps using `char` when this seems obsolete. Is the size of a char sufficient after all? I know there are additional "helper" characters for "upgrading" other characters (turn an o into ö and so on). How are these handled by `char` and code point iteration? Isn't there a chance to horribly corrupt your string if you replace `char`s instead of "whole" code points?

Comment: Maybe see also https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @tripleee I know that website and I agree. But runtimes/compilers for Java/C# and so on do not. They use 16-bit char types internally and as a "normal" programmer you cannot change that. It seems the best you can do is try to work around that, hope nobody will ever use 32-bit chars in your app, and slowly try to use code points instead of chars everywhere. :(

Answer (score 1):

In summary, the answer to the question

> *Isn't a 2-byte char datatype insufficient to deal with the concept of "characters" in a Unicode string?*

is *Yes, it's insufficient to store a Unicode character, but you don't need to worry because you don't use and shouldn't use it to iterate*

See also

- [Is 16-bit wchar_t formally valid for representing full Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39548465/995714)
- [What's "wrong" with C++ wchar_t and wstrings? What are some alternatives to wide characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11107608/995714)

For more details read below

---

> Shouldn't you always use the methods that operate on code points when dealing with strings?

One should almost never do that, because contrary to popular belief, **characters in UTF-32 does *not* have a fixed length**. UTF-32 is only a fixed-length encoding for a *single code point*, but a *user-perceived character* may be represented by multiple code points:

> *It is important to recognize that what the user thinks of as a “character”—a basic unit of a writing system for a language—may not be just a single Unicode code point. Instead, that basic unit may be made up of multiple Unicode code points. To avoid ambiguity with the computer use of the term character, this is called a user-perceived character. For example, “G” + grave-accent is a user-perceived character: users think of it as a single character, yet is actually represented by two Unicode code points. These user-perceived characters are approximated by what is called a grapheme cluster, which can be determined programmatically.*
>
> *Grapheme cluster boundaries are important for collation, regular expressions, UI interactions, segmentation for vertical text, identification of boundaries for first-letter styling, and counting “character” positions within text.*
>
> [Unicode Text Segmentation - Grapheme Cluster Boundaries](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)

So we should only use graphemes A.K.A *user-perceived characters* instead and must not break segments into code points. For example people usually iterate strings to **find a specific character**, and if we want to find an ear of rice  *U+1F33E* then it'll match ‍ unexpectedly because that farmer emoji is encoded as *U+1F468 U+200D U+1F33E*. And then that index may be used to **take a substring** from  to something else, which may surprise the user a lot. See [Why are emoji characters like 👩‍👩‍👧‍👦 treated so strangely in Swift strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618487/995714)

Another common mistake is that people **truncate a string** to the first or last `N` characters and append/prepend `"..."` to fit it into the UI when it's too long, and then it breaks miserably because the `char` at index `N` may be in the middle of a grapheme cluster. For example `"‍‍‍‍️‍❤️‍‍"` is a not-quite-long string of *3 user-perceived characters* but it's made from **21 code point**s so if you truncate at the 20th character then it'll mess up the output string completely. Or check the Indic string `"ফোল্ডার"` which can be easily seen has having *4 characters* by selecting or iterate through it with mouse or arrow keys (although I must admit I'm not an expert in any Indic languages), yet it's encoded as **7 code points** (*U+09AB U+09CB U+09B2 U+09CD U+09A1 U+09BE U+09B0*) and will behave badly when truncated in the middle. **Reversing a string or finding palindromes** will have the same fate if not account for multi-codepoint characters

**Indic and Arabic languages (Kannada, Bengali, Thai, Burmese, Lao, Malayalese, Hindi, Persian, Arabic, Tamil...) make very heavy use of [ZWJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) and [ZWNJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) to modify characters.** And in those languages characters also combine with each other or modify each other when there's no ZWJ as in the previous example string. Some other examples: நி (*U+0BA8 U+0BBF*), षि (*U+0937 U+093F*). If you delete a code point in the middle or take a substring then it might not work as expected. Many languages like Burmese, Mongolian, CJKV... as well as mathematical symbols and emojis also utilize [Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_%28Unicode_block%29) [Selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_Supplement) ([VS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974668/995714)) to adjust the previous character. For example က︀ (U+1002 U+FE00), ဂ︀ (U+1000 U+FE00), င︀ (U+1004 U+FE00), ⋚︀ (U+22DA U+FE00), 丸︀ (U+4E38 U+FE00). [Here's the complete list of the alternate variants](https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/StandardizedVariants.txt). Removing the VS will change the rendering of the document which may affect the meaning or readability. You can't arbitrarily easily take a substring in an internationalized application

You can check out [An Introduction to Writing Systems & Unicode - Complex script rendering](https://r12a.github.io/scripts/tutorial/part3) and [Complex text layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout) if you're interested in more information about those scripts

Some people have mentioned the use of [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) segments like g̈ (*U+0067 U+0308*), Å (*U+0041 U+030A*) or é (*U+0065 U+0301*), but that's just a *tiny* not-so-common use case where a character is represented by multiple code points, and are usually convertible to a [precomposed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character). In many other languages such combining sequences are far more common and are detrimental to the rendering of the texts. I'm going to give some examples below (in brackets `[]`) along with some rules stated in [Unicode Text Segmentation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/):

> - ***Do not break Hangul syllable sequences.***
>
>   - [ In Korean characters can be composed from [Jamos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hangul_jamo): 훯 (*U+D6E0 U+11B6*), 가 (*U+1100 U+1161*), 각 (*U+1100 U+1161 U+11A8*), 까ᇫ (*U+1101 U+1161 U+11EB*). No one would consider those multiple characters apart from [some weird standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201009-00/?p=104351) ]
> - ***Do not break before extending characters or ZWJ.***
>
>   - [ For example Indic characters like ണ്‍ (*U+0D23 U+0D4D U+200D*), ല്‍ (*U+0D32 U+0D4D U+200D*), ര്‍ (*U+0D30 U+0D4D U+200D*), क्‍  (*U+0915 U+094D U+200D*) ]
> - ***Do not break within emoji modifier sequences or emoji zwj sequences.***
>
>   - [ ‍♀️ (*U+1F3C3 U+1F3FB U+200D U+2640 U+FE0F*), ‍♀️ (*U+1F3C3 U+1F3FF U+200D U+2640 U+FE0F*), ‍‍‍ (*U+1F469 U+200D U+1F469 U+200D U+1F466 U+200D U+1F466*), ‍‍‍ (*U+1F468 U+200D U+1F469 U+200D U+1F466 U+200D U+1F466*), ‍️ (*it's a single super-wide emoji, not two, combining from U+1F636 U+200D U+1F32B U+FE0F*), ‍❤️‍ (*U+1F468 U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F468*), ‍❤️‍ (*U+1F469 U+1F3FC U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F468 U+1F3FD*), ‍❤️‍‍ (*U+1F469 U+1F3FB U+200D U+2764 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F48B U+200D U+1F469 U+1F3FF*), ‍ (*U+1F431 U+200D U+1F680*), ‍ (*U+1F431 U+200D U+1F464*), ‍ (*U+1F431 U+200D U+1F409*), ‍ (*U+1F431 U+200D U+1F4BB*), ‍ (*U+1F431 U+200D U+1F453*), ‍ (*U+1F431 U+200D U+1F3CD*),  (*U+1F467 U+1F3FB*),  (*U+1F935 U+1F3FB*), ❤️ (*U+2764 U+FE0F*), 1️⃣ (*U+0031 U+FE0F U+20E3*), ⚕️ (*U+2695 U+FE0F*), ©️ (*U+00A9 U+FE0F*), ®️ (*U+00AE U+FE0F*), ‼️ (*U+203C U+FE0F*), ™️ (*U+2122 U+FE0F*), ☑︎ (*U+2611 U+FE0E*),  ‍☠ (*U+1F3F4 U+200D U+2620 U+FE0F*), ️‍⚧ (*U+1F3F3 U+FE0F U+200D U+26A7 U+FE0F*), ️‍ (*U+1F3F3 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F308*) ]. Note: Some of the above emojis may not display properly on your system, because they're platform-specific
> - ***Do not break within emoji flag sequences. That is, do not break between regional indicator (*RI*) symbols if there is an odd number of RI characters before the break point.***
>
>   - [ State/region flags are typically created by 2 regional indicator symbols, for example  (*U+1F1FB U+1F1F3*),  (*U+1F1FA U+1F1F8*),  (*U+1F1EC U+1F1E7*),  (*U+1F1EF U+1F1F5*),  (*U+1F1E9 U+1F1EA*),  (*U+1F1EB U+1F1F7*),  (*U+1F1EA U+1F1FA*),  (*U+1F1FA U+1F1F3*) ]. Note: You may just see the letters, most notably on Windows because MS somehow refused to add flag emojis to their platform
>
> [Grapheme Cluster Boundary Rules](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundary_Rules)

---

> I'm afraid someone will have to explain to me why the world keeps using char when this seems obsolete.

As said, no one should iterate over `char`s in a string, regardless of whether the `char` is 1, 2 or 4-byte long. The *most correct* way is to iterate the graphemes instead. A good Unicode library like ICU will help you. This has also been mentioned in the Unicode document above

> *As far as a user is concerned, the underlying representation of text is not important, but it is important that an editing interface present a uniform implementation of what the user thinks of as characters. Grapheme clusters can be treated as units, by default, for processes such as the formatting of drop caps, as well as the implementation of text selection, arrow key movement or backspacing through text, and so forth. For example, when a grapheme cluster is represented internally by a character sequence consisting of base character + accents, then using the right arrow key would skip from the start of the base character to the end of the last accent.*
>
> [Unicode Text Segmentation - Grapheme Cluster Boundaries](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries)

Unfortunately in many cases that's not possible due to a lack of a proper Unicode library, so in that case one can *iterate the code points* instead, but they need to be careful to avoid matching or cutting the strings in the middle of a grapheme, breaking the user-perceived character

In fact many modern languages prevent you from iterating bytes in a string by having a type typically called ["rune"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19310700/995714) instead, which is actually UTF-32 under the hood, and **avoid the classic `char` completely** or just have that as a legacy type. For example in Go we have [`rune`](https://go.dev/blog/strings) and in C# there's [`System.Text.Rune`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=net-5.0). In rust the [strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html) are [stored in UTF-8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) but [iterations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-02-strings.html#methods-for-iterating-over-strings) are done in [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html) (which represents a Unicode scalar value instead of *byte*):

```rust
for b in "नमस्ते".bytes() {
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

Loops in python3 are done in a similar way:

```py
>>> s = "abc\u20ac\U00010302\U0010fffd"
>>> len(s)
6
>>> for c in s:
...     print('U+{:04X}'.format(ord(c)))
...     
U+0061
U+0062
U+0063
U+20AC
U+10302
U+10FFFD
```

As can be seen, you never loop through each *byte* in them. String iterations are done on runes instead, so the underlying string encoding is completely irrelevant. An implementation can use UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 or any Unicode encodings and the user still don't know anything about that because they only interact with runes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So, you should use "grapheme clusters" if you want to iterate through "charcter positions" in a text, correct? The question was asked because the standard API for getting a substring or the Nth character, or replace in a string in both Java and C# works on 2-byte chars. There is a way to iterate code-points, which are 4-byte and thus slightly better, but, I agree, still not enough. AFAIK there is nothing better in the standard lib for this. In almost all code I'm seeing, there is no attention paid to dealing with "characters" of >2 bytes in string ops. :(

Comment: yes, it's a bit unfortunate, probably because Unicode is too complex and much slower. Handing code points is far easier so they'll go that way instead

Comment: But it does not matter if it's slower when it's just not the correct way...? Relying on code points alone is insufficient to implement "human-expected" character behaviour and you need grapheme clusters, no? "You don't need to worry because you don't use it to iterate", well, yes I do, because almost everyone DOES use it to iterate. `foreach(var c in string) { ... }` or `s.replaceAll("a", "")` can easily destroy "human-expected" characters, no? You just want to remove all "a"s and end up also destroying characters where the "a" is just 2 bytes in the middle of a grapheme cluster, no?

Comment: @AyCe correct. The simplest way to fix a lot of the problems is to normalize the string. Probably language makers think that's the way to do. If you want even better result then there's no way other than using a proper Unicode library

Comment: If the language or a framework implements strings with a "central" string type and string processing functions performed on it and has UI components that display these compound characters correctly, I would expect the entire language to get this right. We went from 1-byte characters to 2-byte characters, which made things a little bit better, but still not conformant to the actual standard. Strings just being char arrays is essentially just as bad as strings being just byte arrays. Yes, but also no, you can't use it the naive way you might expect to. All the broken programs because of this...

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this is a Western world point of view, in parallel we had Asian language history and evolution, which I skip. In any case, most of character set converted, with Unicode*

Historically we had ASCII. In reality, we had also other character encoding, some also without distinguishing lower and upper case, but then ASCII became de facto standard (on western computers, which us Latin scripts). ASCII was not sufficient, so there were some extensions: "code pages", so still every character were 8-bit, but one could select which character set to use (and so which language to support).

All common-used, modern, operating systems were born on such epoch. So programs started with such convention, filesystems, API, text files, etc.

But Internet, and exchanging files were more and more common, so a file produced in Stockholm, were not completely readable in Germany, or in US. ISO standardized some code page (e.g. Latin-1, etc.), which had ASCII + some characters in common, and some parts were different according the encoding. And Windows used the Latin-1 and filled the non-allocated space (you see that it is described as "ANSI"). But also Asian scripts became also important (better computer, so we could effort much more characters for everyday use, not just for typesetting).

So Unicode (and ISO) started to develop a new standard. One set for every character, compatible with all most common charset (so you can transform into Unicode, and back, without losing information: this really helped to do a smooth transition). And such new charset should have 16-bit codepoints [WARNING: this is no more true, but it was so on first Unicode versions]. (for this reason, we have many combining characters, the "Han unification" (merging Chinese, Japanese, and old Korean characters into one), and the special case of encoding the new Korean characters.

New languages adopted such version, so 16bit Unicode characters.

Some operating systems added new API, with these 16-bit characters (Microsoft Windows did together with long names, on filesystem, and in a compatible way, so old computers could read files [just short names, and with 8-bit characters]). In this manner, you had compatibility with old programs, but new programs could (they were not forced) to use the new Unicode.

Old languages and Unix waited, struggling on how to get compatibly AND new Unicode.

This seems your world (as in your question), so early 1990s.

Guess what? 16-bit was not sufficient. So new (now already old) Unicode added planes, and surrogates. Surrogates were a trick to keep allocated 16-bit Unicode valid, but allowing (by using surrogates), to create characters to 0x10FFFF. This was also a difference with ISO, which allowed 31-bit code points.

In the same time, also UTF-8 emerged, so making compatible with ASCII (and with the end-of-string `\0` used by many libraries/operating systems), but allowing all new Unicode characters.

Some more modern languages started to implement UTF-32 (so using 32-bit Unicode), some old adapted (e.g. new API), some just keep the surrogate, so changing "code-point" into "code-unit". Python is one of the exception: old language which converted to full Unicode (and now internally, it selects the optimal size 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit), but Python 3 conversion but very painful (and incompatible with old code, and after 10 years, many libraries were not ready), so I think other old language will think twice, before trying to "upgrade".

The problem on your "problem" is that to get 16-bit (or 32-bit) character, you need a flag day. Everybody should update, every program and every operating system, on the same day. So you should check old past code, and adapt. Or having two set of libraries and practically all operating system split in two: using old characters, or using the new one.

Personally, I think the Unix way is the best one, so using UTF-8: keep ASCII compatible, and extend. Old programs could process (transparently) Unicode characters, also if they were built before Unicode epoch (for printing, for storage, transmission, etc. obviously to get semantic of characters, they need to be Unicode aware).

Because of code unit (so two 16-bit code unit are sometime required for one Unicode code point), and combining characters (do not assume one glyphs is described just by one code-point), and variants selectors, emojis variants/tags, etc., it makes not much sense to iterate and modify single characters. And we should not forget that fonts may design a glyphs from various "characters".

So, it is too difficult to go to a UTF-32 globally, for all languages, because of existing programs and infrastructure. Now that UTF-8 seems to be dominant, I think we should keep UTF-8: so people will uses Unicode libraries, or just handle byte sequences transparently (maybe just merging, templating, etc.), maybe simple search (for ASCII, else the Unicode string must be normalized).

Comment: Actually the ISO-646 variant used in Sweden was *almost* identical to the ISO-646 variant used in Germany. Yüu cüuld figure üut hüw to read it.

Comment: @tripleee: Are you sure about ISO-646? So the 7-bit, without `[`, `{`, etc. which causes the "triplet" implementation in C. I was meaning 8859-1, but I was wrong, Sweden uses Latin1, the "North European" (Latin-4) is not for what we usually think for North Europe

Comment: Yeah, in 646 there were a number of local variants, where for example ASCII `}` mapped to å in Swedish, and ü in German. Weirdly Sweden also had ü even though its use in Swedish is quite marginal, on a different code point (`^` IIRC). ISO-8859-1 took over in the 1990s in most of Western Europe, which then brought some relief for communicating between countries which both used this encoding.

Comment: I don't recall seeing the other Latin-n encodings in active use at the time; for example in Finland, ISO-8859-1 was ubiquitous even though it lacked a few characters which are used (in just a few loan words) in Finnish.

Comment: So you are saying that it IS insufficient, but no one in the western world cares? I still see people recommending indexof(char), split(char), substring(char index), all functions that CANNOT work correctly when using the full supported range of unicode. It seems like madness to me, it's not like unicode was released last year...

Comment: "*So you are saying that it IS insufficient, but no one in the western world cares?*" - no, he's saying that most of the world has moved on from the old UCS-2 way of handling Unicode codepoints and now uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) instead, which is backwards compatible with UCS-2 for codepoints in the 1st Unicode plane (the BMP), supporting the rest of Unicode via surrogates (or using UTF-8, or in some cases UTF-32).  UTF-16 is a compromise between storage size and processing efficiency. Your examples are for cases where code hasn't upgraded to UTF-16, or doesn't need to

Comment: @AyCe: no, but Unicode (in principle) wanted base character and accents to be encoded in two code points (or more), from beginning (and it was a soft-requirements, in order to use just 65536 characters). Just programmers seem to think that one character is one glyph. Languages and scripts are very complex, simple algorithms doesn't work well (read original TeX book: it was just for English, but you see the multiple problems on good typesetting [MS Word does a very bad job]). And this just without the complexity of fonts: "merging codepoints" depend on variant, language, script type, font...

Comment: If you want to search a string within the text, you should use K normalization. Comparison and sorting: C normalization. [either with general Unicode algorithms, or language specific algorithms]. For security: consider equal glyphs that are equal or very similar. To split line, words, cursor highlight: there is an annex. It is all very well documented in annexes of Unicode. Emojis (with requires more then 16bit) are an other world (colours in fonts, variants, tag selectors, direction, etc.).

Comment: @RemyLebeau and Giacomo Catenazzi That's all well and good, but no noticable fraction of programmers is going to abandon the regular methods that use chars anytime soon. This is the stuff that's still taught to newcomers. My examples are everyday string operations. In fact I think I've never seen correct Unicode handling regarding these operations in any code base I've looked at or worked with so far. This just confirms my suspicion that these methods ARE insufficient yet we still continue using them and telling others to use them.

Comment: @AyCe: possibly these are just details. Are you sure programmers do a lot of single character handling? If you do protocols, it is ok (but if you look, these are more "binary" (fixed values) than text handling. If you start to split presentation from program, or i18n, you go instantaneous to just copy strings and "templating". Multiline (line split), fonts, etc. are handled by libraries. String ordering, search etc. are also often done by libraries(because of flexibility). Note: we have many question in SO about failures with character programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. There are roughly three separate cases here.

1. Languages and platforms which only support 16-bit characters (UCS-2). These cannot support the full Unicode range (notably, recent emoji additions are outside the BMP) but can trivially use 16 bits for everything related to Unicode characters. (You can still mess up by losing track of where you are inside a string, though it should be easy to avoid such errors by always making sure you are at an even byte offset.)
2. Languages and platforms which support UTF-16 (including surrogates). As you note, you have to know that a single code point can be more than 16 bits, and adjust accordingly. I'm sure there are many Java applications which actually foul up surrogates if you only care to test them.
3. Languages and platforms which map everything to some internal representation. Ideally there should not even be a way to address the underlying bytes directly unless you specifically need to go there. (Compare with how Python gives you `str` unless you specifically `decode` into `bytes`, or vice versa. It's still possible to mess up if you just copy/paste code from Stack Overflow without understanding what it does.)

Your question sort of presupposes that `char` and `int` are exposed and well-defined, but many languages do not easily let you access underlying byte representations with the versatility / abandon of C.

As for the "why", basically Java predates UTF-16 and certainly UTF-8. It's always harder to retrofit a new model onto an existing language and its libraries than to get it right from the start.

When I am writing this, "right" basically means UTF-8, but it's not entirely unproblematic either, though the kind of futzing you need with surrogates etc isn't necessary or useful (or, if you look at it from the other direction, the normal case is now somewhat futzier, but generally for good reasons); the remaining problems are typically endemic to Unicode (normalization of code points, locale-specific collation, rendering support, etc). Perhaps future generations will smirk at this, too. https://utf8everywhere.org/ contains a lot more around how UTF-8 at least shields us from many mistakes which are still common in the 16-bit world.

Comment: 1. These seem to be about 90% of all applications. I'm exaggerating, but most applications seem to use Java, C# or a C-like language that treats strings as arrays of chars of 2 bytes. 2. These seem to be the methods that render those strings from 1. But as soon as any logic is done on these strings using char-based methods, they would inevitably corrupt certain inputs. 3. True, working with the bytes of a string is for I/O stuff and only useful if you have an encoding (like UTF8) specified. I **HOPE** that the situation is better than I make it. UTF8 everywhere, great - tell that to Java/C#...

Comment: @AyCe "*most applications seem to use Java, C# or a C-like language that treats strings as arrays of chars of 2 bytes*" - in UTF-16 format, yes. Not in UCS-2.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which does not change the fact that an "unicode character" may not fit in 2 bytes (aka `char`), which is exactly what those languages are using to represent "unicode characters". Rendering text may take following characters into account, but doing split, substring etc. I'm pretty sure do not.

Comment: @AyCe "*doing split, substring etc. I'm pretty sure do not*" - only if you are using routines that are not surrogate-aware.

Comment: C itself is agnostic and so obviously many naïve programs simply continue to work flawlessly on non-Windows platforms. I don't use Windows so maybe that's why I rarely see any breakage (and anyway, friends don't let friends use Windows). Still, I'd wager that even on Windows, a large portion of programs which manipulate text don't stumble, either because they do it right, or because their text manipulation is so trivial as to not expose any bugs; and the rest probably only break on surrogates.

Comment: Anyway, the entire https://utf8everywhere.org/ pamphlet is resounding proof that UTF-16 is by and large overcomplicated and in practice insufficient. I basically tried to condense it from memory, but upon rereading it now, I see that it contains a lot more than I remembered, all of it basically answering your question in much more detail.

Comment: See also this post which they link to: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful