# What can I store in a char?

Tags: c++, char, integer, emoji

I know that letters/one-digit-numbers can be stored in chars,

```cpp
char letter = 'c';
char number = '1';
```

but can emojis or forgain letters be stored in a char? If not, how can I store them?
Is this possible without strings?

Comment: You would store it in a string with utf8 encoding.

Comment: See "[Confusing sizeof(char) by ISO/IEC in different character set encoding like UTF-16](//stackoverflow.com/q/29338126/90527)", "[std::wstring VS std::string](//stackoverflow.com/q/402283/90527)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [char vs wchar\_t when to use which data type](//stackoverflow.com/q/45677774/90527)

Comment: You may want to read this: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 4):

A `char` is typically 8 bits. It may be signed or unsigned (it's up to the compiler), so may have any integer value from `-128` to `127` (for signed) or `0` to `255` (for unsigned). If a character can be encoded in that range then it can be stored in a single `char` variable.

There's also wide characters (`wchar_t`) whose size depends again on compiler and operating system. They are usually at least 16 bits.

Then there are explicit Unicode characters, `char8_t` for UTF-8 encoded characters (will be added in the C++23 standard, so might not be widely available yet), `char16_t` for 16-bit characters in UTF-16 encoding, and `char32_t` for 32-bit characters in UTF-32 encoding.

For emojis, or just Unicode characters in general, a single `char` is usually not enough. Use either (multiple) `char`s/`char8_t`s in UTF8 encoding, or use (possibly multiple) `char16_t`s, or use `char32_t`. Or, if you're targeting Windows and using the Windows API, they use 16-bit `wchar_t` for UTF-16 encoded characters.

Comment: even a single `char32_t` isn't enough because [lots of characters are made up from multiple Unicode code points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69414798/995714): ️‍‍❤️1️⃣ ‍‍‍‍️‍❤️‍‍