# converting utf8 to utf32

Tags: c++, boost, utf, c++23

I really am unable to find any help online! just like I have seen in many c++23 programs, what I want to do is:

```
for(char32_t c : utf8string | utf8to32())
```

so that I can work on each individual code-point. preferably I'd like to use boost::locale for that since I already did do a

```
boost::locale::normalize(in.begin(),in.end(),boost::locale::norm_nfc)
```

in the constructor. online I've seen mention of some mysterious boost/text/transcode_iterator.hpp which does not exist on my system.  but even that wouldn't provide the right class for above utf8to32. any hints on where I could find that? how do I even go about writing such a class? obviously I need to warp around another iterator over the existing iterator of std::string. and then I need to put that new iterator into a container so it is treated as such in the for loop? any examples out there how to do that if I already found a fitting iterator implementation?

just to be clear: I want to read utf8 code-points, compare them to some given code-points and maybe mark where they are for future use. easy to do in 7-bit ascii, how do I do it in utf8? not like there's plenty of fully 21-bit utf8-capable grammar-parsers around yet...

Comment: When I needed to work with UTF-8 text, and did not know anything about it, I simply read the Wikipedia page that explains how it works, and after an hour or so, of hacking, I wrote the code that I needed. There are very, very few magic buttons in C++ that do all the work for you, that only need to be located and pushed, somewhere. This isn't one of them. For everything else one needs to roll up their sleeves and ***do all the work themselves***.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to decode UTF-8 manually. You are on the right track that you can write a custom iterator that reads `char`s from the normal string iterator and decodes them into `char32_t` values. To get the syntax you want, you can then overload `operator|` to return an object that exposes your custom iterator.

Comment: Individual code points are mostly useless anyway.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik there's [`codecvt<char32_t,char,mbstate_t>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) and [`codecvt_utf8<char32_t>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) to convert UTF-8 to UTF-32 since C++11. There are also `std::mbrtoc32` and `std::c32rtomb`

Comment: as @n.m.couldbeanAI said, iterating individual code points isn't meaningful. You need to [iterate the user-perceived characters which may be a sequence of multiple code points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69414798/995714)

Comment: @phuclv No, most people don't need that either.

Comment: to be honest I'm more worried about breaking utf8-syntax than about counterintuitive program behaviour. user specifies what to search for, their fault if it breaks a glyph after getting shuffled. @phuclv your solution is nice and actually found that too, but it is not well-documented and little to no examples exist for those two being used outside from streams. but thanks for the link to user-perceived characters I now know that some glyphs are actually 64bit (or rather 40bit) in size, quite hard but still possible to fit that into a template argument. and I'll need to check next code-point...

Answer (score 2):

1. Boost.Text is a proposed library, not an actual part of Boost. You can download it from Github, but it won't be in your package manager just now.
2. Boost actually has several implementations of what you want, more or less, in particular `boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp` has `u8_to_u32_iterator` class which seems particularly close.
3. If you are not firmly set on using iterator adaptors, ranges, or other such machinery, I would recommend https://github.com/simdutf/simdutf, which is a Unicode transcoding library built for speed.
4. Having said that, you don't really need it. If you only need to check your input stream against several characters, just store these characters as UTF-8 strings, and compare to subsequences of your stream. As an optimisation, you can skip characters which cannot start a UTF-8 sequence (a really simple check to write).

Comment: also this answer is lacking examples. in 4. there's no reference (link) to which characters cannot start utf8. search-text in my case is given as template-parameters, utf8-string isn't allowed there, just individual (char32_t-)characters. guess now I'll need to implement a new u64"" class though, as it turns out users could want to find 2-codepoint characters or explicitely their 1-codepoint version. sadly constexpr support is lacking in utf-handling...

Comment: @user11566470 "also"? I have a feeling a comment went missing. I'd not be surprised if it was flagged/automatically moderated due to code of conduct. That's because your complaint about 4. isn't valid. Your answer is really just here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. It's also pretty funny that you complain about a lack of sample code, when you in  your own comment do hand-waving about ~"search text as char32_t template parameters", which has zero relation with any code in the question. I think this answer represents a wealth of practical and actual experience in the field.