# Empty string with length > 0 in R

Tags: r, string, nlp, emoji

I got a weird case in my dataframe while working with emojis in R. I want to delete all emojis for a sentiment analysis. When I do this I got some cases, where the string should be empty, but isn't. What is the problem? I would like to replace empty fields with `NA`. Here a little example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c("test","♥️♥️♥"))

nchar(df$x[2])

df_new <- df |>
  mutate(x = str_remove_all(x, "[[:emoji:]]"))

is_empty(df_new$x[2])
```

Now I would like to use the following command, but this doesn't work, because the string is not empty.

```
tmp <- df_new |>
  mutate(x = na_if(x, ""))
```

What is the problem here and how I can solve this?

Thank you in advance,

Aaron

Comment: It looks like your result would return true if you use `is.null` instead of `is_empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all non-characters but support any language and if you already split up your x values as words you can simply do:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("test","♥️♥️♥"))

library(stringi)

df %>%
  mutate(x = stri_extract_all(x, charclass = "\\p{L}"))

     x
1 test
2   NA
```

If you have strings with multiple words you can slightly adapt above and use this instead

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Ελλάδα means Greece ♥️ ️", "test","♥️♥️♥"))

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(x = paste(stri_extract_all(x, charclass = "\\p{L}")[[1]], collapse = " "))

1 Ελλάδα means Greece
2 test           
3 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run `charToRaw(df_new$x[2])` you can see the bytes left in the string

```
charToRaw(df_new$x[2])
# [1] ef b8 8f ef b8 8f
```

Those appear to be [variant selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974668/what-is-the-unicode-variation-selector) commands for the emoji which are not included in the ":emoji:" character class so they are not removed.

What exactly do you want to keep? It might be easier to write a regular expression for that. There are a lot of weird unicode code points out there.

You could try to remove those values using the regular expression from [here](https://github.com/shinnn/variation-selector-regex)

```
df_new <- df |>
  mutate(x = str_remove_all(x, "[[:emoji:]]")) |>
  mutate(x = str_remove_all(x, "[\\u180B-\\u180D\\uFE00-\\uFE0F]|\\uDB40[\\uDD00-\\uDDEF]"))
```

But you want to check for contents with `nchar(df_new$x)`, not `is_empty`. An empty string is not "empty": `is_empty("")` returns FALSE.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast answer. I just want to keep words. No Emojis, Special Characters or punctuation.