# Best way to get a "back" nav button with the arrow icon in it?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Apple frequently uses a left arrow icon in the their navigation controller "back" button, rather than the word "back" or other text:

[image]

It doesn't seem possible to assign an image to this special button with the standard SDK. Am I missing something obvious? If not, what's the most effective way of achieving this? (Can it be done without Photoshopping the whole button in multiple states?)

Thanks.

Comment: See this discussion as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a UIBarButtonItem with the image and assign it as the `backBarButtonItem` property of your view controller's navigationItem.

Comment: I'll be darned. I had no idea it would realize the back button was special and work anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-initWithImage:style:target:action:` of `UIBarButtonItem` and put your image instead.

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
              style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style
             target:(id)target
             action:(SEL)action
```