# Adding the little arrow to the right side of a cell in an iPhone TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

This should be simple enough.

I have an iPhone app with a TableView. How do I add the little classic arrow to the righthand side of each cell?

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Just set the respective ***accessoryType*** property of *UITableViewCell*.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

In **Swift 3**,

```
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

Comment: Note that if you want to **rotate** the arrow ... **you can not do it**.  You have to use an image .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836606/use-table-view-disclosure-indicator-style-for-uibutton-ios

Comment: For Swift just use cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

Comment: `cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator` works in Swift, too.

Comment: SWIFT 3.0:       cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

Answer (score 72):

You can do this in Interface Builder. Simply click click on the **Table View**, go to **Prototype Cells** on the right side and make it 1.  Then click that **Prototype Cell** and on the right look for **Accessory**.  In the drop-down, click **Disclosure Indicator**.

[image: Interface Builder example]

Comment: I cannot see anything like "Prototype cells" in my xCode... Is it available in some versions of xCode?

Comment: I also cannot find "Prototype Cells".  I've used cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; in custom cell.

Comment: hey @rzv can you enlarge the image just a bit more? i forgot my glasses

Answer (score 8):

### IN SWIFT 5

Use

```
cell.accessoryType = .detailButton
```

for a small Info-button on the right.
[image]

```
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

for a small Info-arrow on the right.
[image]

```
cell.accessoryType = .detailDisclosureButton
```

for a small Info-button and Info-arrow on the right.
[image]

infront of your `return cell`

Answer (score 7):

You can set little classic arrow like two way as below

1) Using inbuilt accessory type method of UITableViewCell

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
```

2) Creating own accessory view with own image

(I) Drag & drop an arrow image(i.e. circle_arrow_right.png) in your project

(II) In cell design method for every row as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Write below code:

```
if (cell ==nil) {
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    //For creating custom accessory view with own image
    UIImageView *accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [accessoryView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle_arrow_right.png"]];
    [cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
    [accessoryView release];

    //Your other components on cells
     .............
    .............

 }
```

[**Note:** Choose appropriate images for accessory view and add in your desired cells. Choose small images for accessory views for better performance.]

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3:**

```
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `accessoryType` property of the cell to show a arrow on the right side. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

for simple arrow:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

and for detailed arrow:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Comment: cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
;)

Answer (score 3):

The other way to do this is to specify `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` when you create the cell. To do this you'll likely alloc init your cell in the tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier delegate method (then proceed to customize and configure your cell).

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator reuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is select `Disclosure Indicator` in `Accessory` section.