# Change the look of leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's “back” style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba)

I did a highly customized button on navigation bar, which is a back button sometimes but a refresh (in a variety of ways) button some other times. So I had to go with leftBarButtonItem instead of backBarButtonItem. What's a good way to make it look like a "back button" when it serves as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `backBarButtonItem` when it needs to be a back button.  When it changes to a refresh, you can use `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES` and then set your own `leftBarButtonItem`.

If you'd like animation, try:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:desiredBarButtonItem animated:YES];
```