# How to convert button into back button in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am changing the root controllers depending on some actions. This prevents me from having a navigation controller that controls all the interactions between my views (a split view controller can only be the root controller while I need a front menu).

When I get to the split view controller, I want to get back to the main menu (done again by changing the root controller) and I have a button for that (named "main menu). I want this "main menu" button to look like a back button ? Is that possible by changing the type of the button ?

Comment: It's not a duplicate I asked if it was possible to change the type of the button. Not how to do a custom back button !

Comment: the title makes it sound very much like a dupe but you are right. Maybe you should stress your point more, make it easier to see that you want to CONVERT one button

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom `UIButton` and assign it a background image similar to the `UINavigationBar` back button, check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

baritems are immutable, you remove and add them. you cannot AFAIK change them  ... you CAN of course make them mutable using a custom UIView as the button's content