# Programmatically created back button has no arrow

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my Xcode Swift project, I have a view controller that has a programatically created back button for the left bar button item.  The text shows up, but the back arrow is missing.  How do I add a back arrow so that it matches the other view controllers in my project?  I'd prefer to not have to use a custom image, but if that is the only way then I'd like to know how to do it.

```
var backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "My List", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605425/create-uibarbuttonitem-with-back-button-style) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba) you'll have to create the image.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: "yourView")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's a bummer but I guess I will go forward with those links.