# In IOS 7 How to make regular navbar button looks like a back button

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

Sometimes the navigation controller is already on the bottom.

However, I want to add a custom button that will allow user to effectively select a left tab.

That back button doesn't have the left chevron.

How do I make that regular button looks like back button?

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/227078/1597744

Comment: Not quite. That's toolbar, not navbar. Also in IOS 7 you can't just change the picture.

Comment: so you are using Toolbar and want to set backbutton ? am i right?

Comment: I want to use Navbar. I think it's obvious from the picture.

Comment: Than whats the problem, create navabarItem and add uibarbutton with custom image.

Comment: Same question here; you found the answer yet?