# Back-like arrow on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I need to add a left bar button item in my app that looks like system back button, but is not the system back button, since it will appear on view controller that is the only vc of my navController's stack and execute my own code. Simply writing "Back" isn't really good for me, as I need to display the "<" arrow as well. Is there a way to programmatically create an arrow like that, without making image with that arrow?

[image: This is how it's supposed to look like]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba)

Comment: Note that the suggested duplicate is a much older question, dating to 2008, with only [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874211/643383) relevant to iOS 7. Further, the OP here has specifically asked for a solution different from that described in that one answer. Let's not be too quick to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a dummy `UIViewController` as a root view controller for your `UINavigationController`’s stack:

```
 [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[UIViewController new]];
 [navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Then you can use my [BackButtonHandler](https://github.com/onegray/UIViewController-BackButtonHandler) extension to handle back button action (as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19132881/1357250)) :

```
 -(BOOL) navigationShouldPopOnBackButton {
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      return NO; 
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use any Unicode character (*anywhere in your code*) for this.

You can find what you want here:

> Xcode > Edit > Special Characters...

Search for `arrow` or `back` or browse the categories.
Then copy paste the character where required (*in the XIB object's title or in the `setTitle` or `setText` methods like any other character*)

something like:
[image]

Comment: There is no arrow in unicode that looks like the one in back (at least not with that size).

Comment: @johnyu : take a screenshot of what you're expecting and add it to your question

Comment: OK, I added the image

Comment: @johnyu : hmm.. i see a few but the only problem is that setting title to "`〈 Back`" exposes the subtle misalignment between the "`〈`" and "`Back`". anyways... i'll check for something good

Comment: I'll probably just have to use the image of that arrow. But thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
// After you create and place your backButton:

UILabel* arrowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 20)];
arrowLabel.text = @"<";
arrowLabel.textColor = [backButton titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
arrowLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,2);
[backButton addSubview:arrowLabel];
```

If addSubview gives you trouble, try

```
[backButton insertSubview:arrowLabel atIndex:0];
```

Comment: +1 for the idea.  Some improvements for positioning and clarity: (1) CGRectMake(-12, -1, 20, 30), (2) arrowLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontofSize:40], (3) MakeScale(0.65,1.25).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `UIBarButtonSystemItem` enum under contants in the UIBarButtonItem documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW2

These are all of the button styles provided by Apple:

```
typedef enum {
   UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
   UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo,        // iOS 3.0 and later
   UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo,        // iOS 3.0 and later
   UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl,    // iOS 4.0 and later
} UIBarButtonSystemItem;
```

Perhaps rewind or undo would be close enough for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, they're completely different thing.