# Xcode - Width and Horizontal Position Are Ambiguous

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, position

I'm trying to figure out how autolayout works and I have run into a problem where I don't understand why I am getting a warning that "The width and horizontal position are ambiguous" for a view. The view is the bottom thin blue line as you can see in the screenshot of the ViewController I am dealing with:

[image: viewController]

The arrow and home buttons do not have any constraints. The constraints for the larger gray view is as follows:

[image: gray view constraints]

The constraints for the "Authors" label is as follows:

[image: Authors label constraints]

And the constraints for the blue thin view is as follows:

[image: blue thin view constraints]

I don't understand why I would be getting this warning since the larger gray view isn't getting the warning but there doesn't seem to be any difference in how I treat the two views. I made sure to include constraints on leading and trailing space for both of them so why is the horizontal position ambiguous for the thin blue one? I can kind of see why the width might be ambiguous but I don't understand why it wouldn't be ambiguous for the larger gray view. Shouldn't autolayout automatically deal with it? I want the width obvious to scale with the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its better not to put such view inside the top bar, just below the greybar would be best for it if your are doing it just for partition. But I have resolved for your way Here.

For blue bar:

1. You are giving "bottom space to:", its not necessary as it is maintained by "height equals:2"
2. you are giving  "leading space to" and "Align to x" thats too don't make sense.

Solution:

Just do this->

1. Give "leading space to: superview(greyview)" and "Trailing space to: superview(greyview)" both value 0
2. Give "top space to:(authors)" certain value
3. And at last "Height Equals to: 2" or as you wish.

[image]

Constraints of greyView

[image]

Constraints of label

[image]

Constraints of Blue bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove Align Center X constraint from the blue thin view.

Side note: it looks like you are trying to create a standard navigation bar. If so, there is a better way to do this:

Select the controller you want as the root of your navigation flow (your "Home" controller, perhaps). Then go to Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. This will put your view controller inside a navigation controller. You can then wire up a Show segue to your Authors controller, and it will automatically have a navigation bar. At runtime the back arrow to Home will appear automatically.

**EDIT:**

Say you have Home and Authors view controllers.

1. Embed the Authors view controller in a navigation controller.
2. Create a Show segue from a button on the Home view controller to the navigation controller that contains the Authors view controller.
3. Within your Authors view controller `viewDidLoad`, add a Home button to dismiss the Authors view controller, like this:

   ```
   self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "goHome"), animated: true)
   ```
4. Add a function to dismiss your Authors view controller when the Home button is tapped:

   ```
   func goHome() {
       self.navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

You would need to do a little extra to get the arrow icon on your Home button. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba) gives some ideas how to do this. If you already have the image, it should be very easy.

Now your Authors view controller is within a real navigation controller, and you can navigate from it to other view controllers, say if user taps an author to get more information.

Comment: I was considering doing this but couldn't find a way to make it work so that the "home" ViewController didn't have a navigation bar but all the other ViewControllers did, which is my goal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I believe you will be happier in the long run if you use a real navigation controller instead of rolling your own. Good luck either way!

Comment: So I tried to do what you suggested and after several hours I gave up on trying to get a back arrow with "home" text as the left button on the nav bar haha. But this is valuable information to know for the future, thanks!