# InterfaceBuilder/Swift: Backbutton Image

Tags: swift, xcode, interface, builder, uinavigationcontroller

Is there a possibility to add the backbutton-image from UINavigationViewControllers to own (custom) buttons?

[image: Custom Button without Image]
[image: Image I want to add]

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolba)

Comment: this one uses a back-button-image from 5 years ago, there should be a better way now

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage.init(named: "backImage")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage.init(named: "backImage")
```